# Get device storage path on android (Firefox Add-on)

Tags: android, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to get path smthing like: `storage/emulated/0` using Firefox Add-On SDK under Android OS. Analog in android sdk is `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Is it possible?

Comment: You want the path to what?

Comment: @Makyen path that contains directories like "Downloads", "DCIM", "/Android/data", "Music"